# Trouble on rspecting a FactoryGirl object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10, RSpec 2 and FactoryGirl. I have the following scenario:

In the `models/user_spec.rb` file I have

```
describe User do
  let(:user) { Factory(:user) }

  it "should have a 'registered' authorization do
    user.authorization.should == "registered"
  end
end
```

In the `factories/user.rb` file I have

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, :class => User do |user|
    user.authorization 'registered'
  end
end
```

In the `user.rb` file I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION = 'registered'

  validates :authorization,
    :inclusion => {
      :in      => Authorization.all.map(&:name),
      :message => "authorization is not allowed"
    },
    :presence  => true

  before_validation :fill_user_create, :on => :create


  private

  def fill_user_create
    self.authorization = Authorization::DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION
  end
end
```

*When I run the `rspec` command I get the following error*:

```
User should have a default 'registered' Authorization
Failure/Error: let(:user) { Factory(:user) }
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
  Validation failed: Users authorization is not allowed
```

**What is exactly the problem and how can I solve that?**

---

*BTW*: In the `models/user_spec.rb` file I can use something like the following

```
let(:user) { User.create }
```

and it will work, but *I prefer to use the FactoryGirl gem*. **What do you advice about?**

Comment: In the fill_user_create method you probably meant to do `self.authorization = Authorization::DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION`

Comment: @eugen - I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try modifying your spec as below and check what the results are:

```
it "should have a 'registered' authorization" do
  system_names = Authorization.all.map(&:system_name)
  system_names.should have_at_least(1).item
  system_names.should include('registered')
  user.authorization.should == "registered"
end
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457403/trouble-on-evaluating-other-model-data for more information.