# Trouble on evaluating other model data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and RSpec 2. In my spec file I have code like the following:

```
describe User do
  let(:authorizations) { Authorization.all.map(&:name) }

   it "should have a 'registered' value" do
     authorizations.should include("registered")
   end
end
```

When I run the above test I get:

```
User should have a 'registered' value
Failure/Error: authorizations.should include("registered")
expected [] to include "registered"
  Diff:
  @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
  -registered
  +[]
```

**Is it possible to solve the above error\problem? If so, how can I do?**

Comment: first, you should populate your test db

Comment: @apneadiving - How can I populate the test database with no "hacking" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574797/how-to-load-dbseed-data-into-test-database-automatically?answertab=votes#tab-top)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above tells me that you have you all empty tables in your test database. You should either consider [seeding](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/5/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-database-seeding) your dev/test databases. (in case your consider Authorization to be a look up kind of entity)

or

using something a [factory girl](http://rpheath.com/posts/411-how-to-use-factory-girl-with-rspec) to create some test data for yourself in the before block of your spec.

Comment: In the blog article related to seeding that you posted there is this phrase (at the end): "But, don’t go overboard and use seeds.rb for test or staging datasets – it should only be used for the base data that is necessary for your app to run". So, should I seed data in the test database?

Comment: Like i have said, if you consider the Authorization table to only every contain lookup data which you expect to be pre-populated when you application goes to production , then yes. Seed your dev database and test too. When I say lookup I mean, a table which will have a small set of values which will never be created by the application and is expected to be present when your application boots up. To me authorization sounds like one to me, but it depends on your domain.

Comment: Look at [this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) and read up more about what "lookup" data means and whats should be seeded vs when fixutures or factory girl should be used.